# Using VS2005 and VSS is there a way to add comments to checkins?

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

All the googling around hasn't found an answer for me yet... I have one of our devs that is using VSS and VS2005.  Checking in works (abeit quite painfully across the 'Net) but there doesn't seem to be a way to put comments into a checkin (unless you embed it in the source file maybe?)  I'll be one of the firs to admit that my knowledge of VSS is pretty slim, and if there's a "Duh" answer, would be happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the View Pending Checkins... collapsible pane in visual studio.  It has a toggle button that exposes a comment box.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2005 there is a "Pending Changes" view that lets you add comments to a single file or group of files to be checked in.  Pending Changes can be accessed via the View menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you missed to add comments due to the "Check In Now" setting, you can still add a CheckIn-comment via

1. check in the file in question
2. right-click on filename in SolutionExplorer
3. View History
4. double click on youngest item
5. adding your comment under Comment

Answer (score 0):

When you go to check in a file(s) there should be the "fast" check in option and the check in option that has the ellipses (...) next to it indicating a dialog will open. When you use this feature to check in/out a file, there is a section in the dialog that allows you to add comments.

Answer (score 0):

When checking in from the VS2005 IDE you should be prompted for check-in comments.  If you are not then you probably have the "Don't show Check In dialog box when checking in items" option ticked in Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment.  Untick and the check-in comment dialog will display when checking in.